# How do I urlencode a POST request in flutter/dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

For reference, here is the CURL command I am trying to replicate in dart/flutter.

```
curl https://example.signalwire.com/api/laml/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Messages.json \
  -X POST \
  --data-urlencode "From=+15551234567" \
  --data-urlencode "Body=Hello World\!" \
  --data-urlencode "To=+15557654321" \
  -u "YourProjectID:YourAuthToken"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

String accountSid = '12345';

String yourAuthToken = '12345';
String yourProjectID = '12345';

String from = '15551234567';
String body = 'Hello World!'
String to = '15557654321'!

String url = 'https://example.signalwire.com/api/laml/2010-04-01/Accounts/$accountSid/Messages.json';

Map<String, String> headers = <String, String>{
  yourProjectID: yourAuthToken,
};

String body = jsonEncode(<String, dynamic>{
  'From': from, 
  'Body': 
  'Hello World\!', 'To': '+15557654321'
});

http.Response response = await http.post(url, body: body, headers: headers);
```